# Django manage.py migrate errors

Tags: python, django, cs50

I've been working on a project for CS50-Web for a while now and I was changing some of my models trying to add a unique attribute to some things. Long story short it wasn't working how I wanted so I went back to how I had it previously and now something is wrong and I can get it to migrate the changes to the model. I don't understand what to do because it was working fine before. Please can someone help I so frustrated and annoyed that I've broken it after so many hours of work. Sorry I know this error code is long but I don't know which part is important.

Error code

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, network, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying network.0019_alter_follower_user...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__network_follower.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\caitw\Documents\GitHub\CS50-Web\Project-4-Network\project4\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\caitw\Documents\GitHub\CS50-Web\Project-4-Network\project4\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 253, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 126, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 156, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 236, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 125, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 225, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 140, in alter_field
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 620, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 362, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 285, in _remake_table
    self.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM %s" % (
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 153, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\caitw\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__network_follower.user_id
```

I went back to how I had the code before it failed but it doesn't work now

Comment: Did you modify the network_follower model to put a unique constraint on user_id?

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the problem. I've just got to work out how to modify the model again now I don't have access through the admin page

Comment: So the problem is that you put a unique constraint on that field, but there were already duplicate rows in the database for that field, so the constraint could not be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Just try these 3 commands for migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #This value will generate afte makemigrations. it can be either 0001, 0002 or more.

python manage.py migrate
```

And see if it solves this error

Answer (score 0):

This answer simple. Make sure that urls.py file in your 'app'/application in any code editor(vscode). After you copy urls.py (from project) to urls.py(app) and pest it.
Make sure you import the incluse line and only set urlpatterns. like(
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [

])

Then if you run migrate command then you can show paricular django files ans databse file.